# Can not authorized user using facebook in laravel

Tags: oauth, laravel-5.1, facebook-authentication

I am trying to use Facebook to authenticate users. It works ok in sometimes and some times it gives following errors:

> local.ERROR: exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException'

with message:

> 'Client error: `POST https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/oauth/access_token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
>   {"error":{"message":"This authorization code has been used.","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"AEtD1wdLUE (truncated...)

Comment: Share the code fragment causing this and provide more information.

Comment: Did you use a library to FB auth like laravel socialite?